# Можно ли упростить цикл, используя java 9 или java 8?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, lambda, java-8

**Можно ли как-то упростить этот цикл, используя java 9 или java 8?**

```
for (String s : list) {
    if (s.indexOf("D") != -1) {
        numberList.addAll(getDoubleFromString(s));
    } else {
        if (s.indexOf(".") != -1) {
            numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s))));
        } else {
            numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(Integer.valueOf(s)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давай-те сделаем оптимизации по шагам (основная сложность непонятно что принимают TypeSatellite и какой тип у numberList, поэтому напишу для object'a):

1) Можно заменить `s.indexOf(...) != -1` на `s.contains(...)`, то есть записать что-то вроде

```
     list.forEach(s -> {
        if (s.contains("D")) {
            numberList.addAll(getDoubleFromString(s));
        } else {
            if (s.contains(".")) {
                numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s))));
            } else {
                numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(Integer.valueOf(s)));
            }
        }
    });
```

2) Можно вынести общий код

```
     list.forEach(s -> {
        if (s.contains("D")) {
            numberList.addAll(getDoubleFromString(s));
        } else {
            Object number = s.contains(".") ? BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s)) : Integer.valueOf(s);
            numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(number));
        }
    });
```

3) Вынесем общий функцию:

```
    list.forEach(s -> {
            numberList.addAll(getListNumber(s));
    });
   }

   private static Collection<Object> getListNumber(String s) {
    if (s.contains("D")) {
        return getDoubleFromString(s));
    } else {
        Object number = s.contains(".") ? BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s)) : Integer.valueOf(s);
        return Collections.singleton(new TypeSatellite(number));
    }
   }
```

4) последний шаг используем стрим

```
 numberList = list.stream().flatMap(::getListNumber ).collect(Collectors.toList());

 private static Stream<Object> getListNumber(String s) {
    if (s.contains("D")) {
        return getDoubleFromString(s).stream();
    } else {
        Object number = s.contains(".") ? BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s)) : Integer.valueOf(s);
        return Stream.of(new TypeSatellite(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: numberList - ArrayList, у TypeSatellite  2 конструктора: первый принимает integer, второй конструктор BigDecimal

Comment: если object передать в качестве параметра в конструктор класса  TypeSatellite, то как мне потом узнать по Object к какому типу нужно приводить к BigDecimal или Integer?

Comment: Так себе оптимизация, если честно.

Comment: @Suvitruf оптимизируете?) и хотелось бы узнать "Есть класс с конструктором, который принимает тип Object. Я создаю 2 экземпляра этого класса и передаю в конструктор тип Integer и тип BigDecimalсоответственно. Как мне в конструкторе определить какой Object ко мне пришел?(Integer или BigDecimal?"

Comment: Так Integer и Double? Или BigDecimal и Integer? Оптимизация какого вида вам нужна по скорости или простоте кода? ArrayList не параметизированный, то есть содержит Object? А как вы его потом используете?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin простите, подправил и по простоте и по скорости, золотую середину:)

Comment: ArrayList<TypeSatellite>

Answer (score 2):

Данный код действительно можно отредактировать с использованием Java 8. Для начала будем руководствоваться тем, что list объявлен следующим образом:

```
List <String> list
```

Воспользуемся функциональным интерфейсом из [java.util.function.Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

```
Predicate <String> containsDouble = s->s.contains("D");
Predicate <String> containsDecimal = s->s.contains(".");
Predicate <String> containsInteger = containsDouble.or(containsDecimal).negate();
```

Первый устанавливает, содержит ли строка "D", второй - точку, третий будет истинным, если первые два одновременно ложны.
Далее мы можем заполнить   numberList с, используя [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

```
list.stream().filter(containsDouble).forEach(s -> numberList.addAll(getDoubleFromString(s)));
list.stream().filter(containsDecimal).forEach(s -> numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.valueOf(s)))));
list.stream().filter(containsInteger).forEach(s -> numberList.add(new TypeSatellite(Integer.valueOf(s))));
```

Замечу, что при этом объект numberList должен быть final или [effectively-final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final). Трудоёмкость алгоритма при этом останется прежней O(N).

Comment: Тут и три прохода по коллекции, и побочный эффект в лямбде. Не надо так.